# How can I perfectly simulate KeyEvents?

Tags: java, keyevent

How can I construct my own `KeyEvent` objects which perfectly (or very closely) match the ones I would receive from a `KeyListener` when the end-user types something?

---

For example, I have a United Kingdom ISO keyboard layout and to type the `"` character I press `Shift+2`. If I record this on a `JFrame` with a `KeyListener`, I receive the following events:

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=16,keyText=Shift,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Shift,extModifiers=Shift,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=16,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=42,extendedKeyCode=0x10] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=50,keyText=2,keyChar='"',modifiers=Shift,extModifiers=Shift,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=50,primaryLevelUnicode=50,scancode=3,extendedKeyCode=0x32] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='"',modifiers=Shift,extModifiers=Shift,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=16,keyText=Shift,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=16,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=42,extendedKeyCode=0x10] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=50,keyText=2,keyChar='"',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=50,primaryLevelUnicode=50,scancode=3,extendedKeyCode=0x32] on frame0
```

I want to create a method which I would give the `"` as a char parameter, and it would return an array of the KeyEvents as listed above.

My problems are:

- In the `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events, `keyChar='"'` represents the character that was pressed (`"`), however the `keyCode=50` refers to the "non-shifted" ASCII value (aka `2`). I need to know how to get this non-shifted value from just the `"` character.
- This non-shifted value will also be different for different keyboard layouts. For example, the US ANSI layout requires `Shift+'` to type the `"` key, which means the `keyCode` would be 39 rather than 50.
- On some keyboard layouts, the shift key is required to type a key, but not on others. The `#` character for example requires `Shift+3` on US ANSI keyboards, but requires no shift press on UK ISO keyboards. I need to know whether I should simulate the shift press/release events and provide a shift modifier.

Any insight on how to solve these problems would be appreciated. I should also note that using the `Robot` class cannot be used in my situation.

Comment: Is the simulation of operating system events disallowed?

Comment: This will depend on what it is your are trying to achieve.  You could take a look at [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) which has the ability to trigger key press/release events or you could "post" `KeyEvent`s directly to the `EventQueue` via [`Toolkit#getSystemEventQueue#post`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemEventQueue%28%29)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you misunderstand. I know *how* to dispatch a KeyEvent to a target. I need to know how to get the data to construct a KeyEvent in a way that it would be identical to a KeyEvent triggered by a user physically typing something from their keyboard.

Comment: Back to the OS or Java application?  Once you dispatch and event, it's the same as a physical key press (as far as the application is concerned), the key events will be delivered to the current focused component...

Comment: Keyboard layout is binded with OS support. Apart from standard keyboards, it is possible to customize a brand new layout by a user, hence there are millions of possibilities. Whether your program supports a layout should totally depend on the OS. It is not a good practice to customize your own MouseEvent, if you want to do so, you need to call native OS-based API to get the keyboard char, however, you don't have to. Doing a Java `KeyEvent` simulation is not as good as OS-level simulation. @MadProgrammer is correct, try to use `Robot` class to do so and make necessary changes to your code.

Comment: BTW, if you are interested to see how MS Windows deals with Keyboard events, you can look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153546(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 6):

There is no "easy" way to translate a virtual key to a actual key sequence or back again, at least not that I've been able to find.

The two main ways of dispatching key events is either via `java.awt.Robot` or directly through the system event queue.  Which you want to use will depend on what it is you want to achieve.

Components generally won't be able to distinguish between key strokes sent from the keyboard of those your generate your self.

The sample below is convoluted, I'm sorry, I found no better way to achieve the requirements I needed.

```
public class TestKeyEvents {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestKeyEvents();
    }
    public TestKeyEvents() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                new Thread(new KeyDispatcher()).start();
            }
        });
    }
    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10, 30);
            area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            area.setLineWrap(true);
            add(area);
        }
    }
    public class KeyDispatcher implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            dispatchKeyEventsViaEventQueue();
            dispatchKeyEventsViaRobot();
        }

        protected void dispatchKeyEventsViaEventQueue() {
            if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                String text = "This is a key sequence dispatched via the event queue\n";
                KeySequence keySequence = getKeySequence(text);
                List<KeyEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Integer> modifers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Key key : keySequence) {
                    events.clear();
                    System.out.println(key);
                    switch (key.getStrokeType()) {
                        case Press:
                            switch (key.getKeyCode()) {
                                case KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT:
                                case KeyEvent.VK_ALT:
                                case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
                                case KeyEvent.VK_META:
                                    if (!modifers.contains(key.getKeyCode())) {
                                        modifers.add(key.getKeyCode());
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    events.add(new KeyEvent(new JPanel(), KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), getModifiers(modifers), key.getKeyCode(), key.getKeyChar()));
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case Release:
                            switch (key.getKeyCode()) {
                                case KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT:
                                case KeyEvent.VK_ALT:
                                case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
                                case KeyEvent.VK_META:
                                    if (!modifers.contains(key.getKeyCode())) {
                                        modifers.remove(key.getKeyCode());
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    events.add(new KeyEvent(new JPanel(), KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, System.currentTimeMillis(), getModifiers(modifers), key.getKeyCode(), key.getKeyChar()));
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case Type:
                            events.add(new KeyEvent(new JPanel(), KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), getModifiers(modifers), key.getKeyCode(), key.getKeyChar()));
                            events.add(new KeyEvent(new JPanel(), KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, System.currentTimeMillis(), getModifiers(modifers), key.getKeyCode(), key.getKeyChar()));
                            events.add(new KeyEvent(new JPanel(), KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, System.currentTimeMillis(), getModifiers(modifers), KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, key.getKeyChar()));
                            break;
                    }

                    for (KeyEvent evt : events) {
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(evt);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dispatchKeyEventsViaEventQueue();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void dispatchKeyEventsViaRobot() {
            try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                String text = "This is a key sequence dispatched via java.awt.Robot\n";
                KeySequence keySequence = getKeySequence(text);
                List<KeyEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Key key : keySequence) {
                    events.clear();
                    System.out.println(key);
                    switch (key.getStrokeType()) {
                        case Press:
                            robot.keyPress(key.getKeyCode());
                            break;
                        case Release:
                            robot.keyRelease(key.getKeyCode());
                            break;
                        case Type:
                            robot.keyPress(key.getKeyCode());
                            robot.keyRelease(key.getKeyCode());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (AWTException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    protected int getModifiers(List<Integer> mods) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int mod : mods) {
            result &= mod;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static class Key {
        public enum StrokeType {
            Type,
            Press,
            Release
        }
        private StrokeType strokeType;
        private int keyCode;
        private char keyChar;
        public Key(StrokeType type, int keyCode, char keyChar) {
            this.strokeType = type;
            this.keyCode = keyCode;
            this.keyChar = keyChar;
        }

        public StrokeType getStrokeType() {
            return strokeType;
        }

        public int getKeyCode() {
            return keyCode;
        }

        public char getKeyChar() {
            return keyChar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getStrokeType().name() + " " + getKeyChar() + " (" + getKeyCode() + ")";
        }
    }

    public static KeySequence getKeySequence(String text) {
        KeySequence ks = new KeySequence();
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            addKeySequence(ks, c);
        }
        return ks;
    }

    public static void addKeySequence(KeySequence ks, char character) {
        switch (character) {
            case 'a':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_A, character);
                break;
            case 'b':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_B, character);
                break;
            case 'c':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_C, character);
                break;
            case 'd':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_D, character);
                break;
            case 'e':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_E, character);
                break;
            case 'f':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_F, character);
                break;
            case 'g':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_G, character);
                break;
            case 'h':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_H, character);
                break;
            case 'i':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_I, character);
                break;
            case 'j':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_J, character);
                break;
            case 'k':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_K, character);
                break;
            case 'l':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_L, character);
                break;
            case 'm':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_M, character);
                break;
            case 'n':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_N, character);
                break;
            case 'o':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_O, character);
                break;
            case 'p':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_P, character);
                break;
            case 'q':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_Q, character);
                break;
            case 'r':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_R, character);
                break;
            case 's':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_S, character);
                break;
            case 't':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_T, character);
                break;
            case 'u':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_U, character);
                break;
            case 'v':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_V, character);
                break;
            case 'w':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_W, character);
                break;
            case 'x':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_X, character);
                break;
            case 'y':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_Y, character);
                break;
            case 'z':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_Z, character);
                break;
            case 'A':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_A, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'B':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_B, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'C':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_C, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'D':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_D, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'E':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_E, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'F':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_F, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'G':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_G, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'H':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_H, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'I':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_I, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'J':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_J, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'K':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_K, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'L':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_L, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'M':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_M, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'N':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_N, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'O':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_O, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'P':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_P, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'Q':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_Q, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'R':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_R, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'S':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_S, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'T':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_T, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'U':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_U, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'V':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_V, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'W':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_W, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'X':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_X, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'Y':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_Y, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case 'Z':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_Z, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case '`':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE, character);
                break;
            case '0':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_0, character);
                break;
            case '1':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_1, character);
                break;
            case '2':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_2, character);
                break;
            case '3':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_3, character);
                break;
            case '4':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_4, character);
                break;
            case '5':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_5, character);
                break;
            case '6':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_6, character);
                break;
            case '7':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_7, character);
                break;
            case '8':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_8, character);
                break;
            case '9':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_9, character);
                break;
            case '-':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS, character);
                break;
            case '=':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS, character);
                break;
            case '~':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case '!':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK, character);
                break;
            case '@':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_AT, character);
                break;
            case '#':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_NUMBER_SIGN, character);
                break;
            case '$':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_DOLLAR, character);
                break;
            case '%':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_5, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case '^':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX, character);
                break;
            case '&':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_AMPERSAND, character);
                break;
            case '*':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_ASTERISK, character);
                break;
            case '(':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS, character);
                break;
            case ')':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS, character);
                break;
            case '_':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case '+':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, character);
                break;
            case '\t':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, character);
                break;
            case '\n':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, character);
                break;
            case '[':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET, character);
                break;
            case ']':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, character);
                break;
            case '\\':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH, character);
                break;
            case '{':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case '}':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case '|':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case ';':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON, character);
                break;
            case ':':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_COLON, character);
                break;
            case '\'':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE, character);
                break;
            case '"':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTEDBL, character);
                break;
            case ',':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA, character);
                break;
            case '<':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_LESS, character);
                break;
            case '.':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD, character);
                break;
            case '>':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_GREATER, character);
                break;
            case '/':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH, character);
                break;
            case '?':
                ks.press(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH, character);
                ks.release(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, '\0');
                break;
            case ' ':
                ks.type(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, character);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
        }
    }

    public static class KeySequence implements Iterable<Key> {
        private List<Key> keys;
        public KeySequence() {
            keys = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public void type(int keyCode, char keyChar) {
            keys.add(new Key(Key.StrokeType.Type, keyCode, keyChar));
        }

        public void press(int keyCode, char keyChar) {
            keys.add(new Key(Key.StrokeType.Press, keyCode, keyChar));
        }

        public void release(int keyCode, char keyChar) {
            keys.add(new Key(Key.StrokeType.Release, keyCode, keyChar));
        }

        public Iterator<Key> iterator() {
            return keys.iterator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to manually code the behaviour of each character. Is there not a more elegant solution?

Comment: Not that I've found, and I spent a lot of time looking. The problem seems to be that there is no way to distinguish between 'S' and 's' :P

Comment: there seems to be an issue with colon, it needs an upgrade :)