# How can I send a custom key event to an applet?

Tags: java, applet, awt, keyevent

Basically I have 2 `JFrame` windows, one of which contains an applet. I am trying to send the key typed to the applet.

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    dispatchKeyTyped(e.getID(),e.getModifiers(),e.getKeyCode(),e.getKeyChar(),e.getKeyLocation());
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    dispatchKeyTyped(e.getID(),e.getModifiers(),e.getKeyCode(),e.getKeyChar(),e.getKeyLocation());
} 

public void dispatchKeyTyped(int id, int modifiers, int keycode, char keychar, int keylocation) {
    applet.getComponent(0).dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(applet,id,System.currentTimeMillis(),modifiers,keycode,keychar,keylocation));
}
```

When I try to do this nothing happens, the key is not send. If I replace the code by sending the `KeyEvent` like this:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    dispatchKeyTyped(e);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    dispatchKeyTyped(e);
} 
public void dispatchKeyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    applet.getComponent(0).dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

This seems to work fine but I want to create the `KeyEvent` myself and not sure why the first example does not work.

Comment: *1 contains an applet* Applets are **dead**.

Comment: dead or not they are still being used.

Comment: check again inputs provided for new, might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867040/how-to-create-a-keyevent

Comment: thanks but it did not help me unfortunate.

Comment: source - The Component that originated the event, so it's doesn't seem like applet. Maybe applet should by `e.getComponent()`

Comment: I tried this aswell and it did not work. but also the other code with the KeyEvent does work using the applet

Comment: as far as i see with proper inputs you should be able to work even with `new KeyEvent()`. Sill thinking of `inputs` and something is not matching.

Comment: Yea that is what is confusing me both should match (I think so)