# Java => shorten commands for robot

Tags: java, input, automation, awtrobot

Hey there using this code snippet:

```
try {

      Robot robot = new Robot();

      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);

 } catch (AWTException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

i get this result :

```
hallo
```

But is there any way to shorten this process ? e.g. something like:

```
try {

       Robot robot = new Robot();

       String  word = "hallo";

       // something like:
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.word);

   } catch (AWTException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I know this example doesn't work, but I couldn't find any documentation about this.

You have any ideas? greetings and thanks

Comment: you could create a method that takes a char input, figures out what letter was passed and then types given char. It would be more code than this, but it will be less hardcoding. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248510/convert-string-to-keyevents) for an example.

Comment: The answer to your question is [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260282/converting-a-char-into-java-keyevent-keycode
The method is provided.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Java 7 then you can use the [`KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar%28int%29) method to get the key code from a char:

```
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 

   [...]

   public static void type(Robot robot, String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(word.charAt(i));
            robot.keyPress(keyCode);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
        }
    }

   [...]

   Robot robot = new Robot();
   type(robot, "hallo");
```

Comment: ok thx but what do i have to import for "getExtendedKeyCodeForChar", otherwise this method is undefined for the type keyevent :/ ?

Comment: `import java.awt.event.KeyEvent` would suffice: `getExtendedKeyCodeForChar` is a static method in the class `KeyEvent`. If you're getting "method is not defined" error then I guess you're using Java 6 or older and you should go with another answer.

Comment: so i should use java 7 yea?

Comment: If you can then by all means do upgrade to Java 7.

Comment: yea i installed, but i cannot change the "execution environment" from my project(the latest is still "Java Se 6"), you know why? (using eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Make a method like this. Simply use the methods that take a character.

```
public void press(String s, Robot r)
{
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray())
    {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

        r.keyPress(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
        r.keyRelease(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    }
}
```

Or you can use this to get the KeyCode.

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ch, 0).getKeyCode();
```

Or also

```
KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(ch);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you forgot release shift key

Comment: @user902383 Shift will be automatically released after pressing any other key.

Comment: what to import for "KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(ch);" ?

Comment: @user3297073 You need to work with Java 1.7 JDK for that to work. Else, use the above methods, they work even with 1.6