# How to detect fn key pressed event in java

Tags: java, javafx, ascii, keyevent

I am sucessfull in creating key pressed event for characters and numbers. But when I press any of the function key, the code doesn't detect it. I have used `.getCharacter()` to get the key pressed. This is what I have done so far

```
@FXML
private void checkKeyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Pressed key : " + e.getCharacter());
}
```

When I press any normal keys, it prints the key but when I press any special key like a function key or esc, it doesn't detect anything. Do I have to first get the `ASCII` value of the key?

Comment: give this a look http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: Please check the below two links [Keycode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260282/converting-a-char-into-java-keyevent-keycode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every Key is mapped to a Character.

Check [`KeyEvent.getCode ()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode--) and the relevant constants in [`KeyCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html).