# It seems that I can't press every button with the robot class

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-events, awtrobot

First off : I'm using an azerty keyboard.
I want to press the button which is in the upper left corner, just below 'escape'.
I believe it's the '~' for qwerty keyboard (for azerty it is '²')

I unsuccesfully search for it's key code then I found this :
[java.awt.event.KeyEvent not capable of fully mappin AZERTY keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599939/java-awt-event-keyevent-not-capable-of-fully-mappin-azerty-keyboard)

Running his code I got this :

```
Pressed : unknown keyCode: 0x0 / ² code = 0
```

By inspecting the keyEvent object while debugging I got this

```
extendedKeyCode = 16777394
keyLocation = 1
id = 401
```

How could I solve this problem?
Do you think I could make my own Implementation of keyEvent, build one that is similar then raise it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just made a loop to press keyEvent from 0 to 10 000 000 and '²' was never pressed.

```
package keyCodeTester;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyCodeTester {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(5000);

        for(int i=41; i<10000000; i++) {
            try {
                if (i>=112 && i<=123) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("touche fonction");
                }
                robot.keyPress(i);
                robot.delay(100);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                robot.delay(100);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                System.out.println("iae pour " + String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I guess robot only works for qwerty.
I'm going to make some C code and call it from java.