# Is there a way to control the keyboard in java without awt.robot

Tags: java, keyboard, awtrobot

Is there a way to control the keyboard in java without using awt.robot?
Unfortunatly the robot class cannot press every key on an azerty layout.

And I need one of them.

The only solution seems to code the equivalent of robot in C then use java to
call it.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're not tied to Java you could use C# instead. Even if you have no experience with C# you should pick it up quickly, the syntax is similar. Documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can type any ascii character by

1. Holding alt
2. Typing the ascii code for the character on the NUMBERPAD
3. Releasing alt

You could get the robot to do this for special characters. Not sure if that solves your problem.

Eg: `hold ALT, type 1234 on the numberpad, release ALT` types Ӓ

Comment: that won't work, I actually need to press the key, it's to open a console in a game. I don't want to change the key in the game settings either.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java Robot with Azerty vrs Qwerty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766470/java-robot-with-azerty-vrs-qwerty) the Window Licker library (https://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/) supports different keyboard layouts. This might help you.

Comment: I aready found this :p and no it does not help. awt robot connot press this touch on an azerty keyboard, I tried every value from 0 to 10000000 and looked what happened in a notepad. see -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965005/it-seems-that-i-cant-press-every-button-with-the-robot-class